# When is the fourier transform of a function locally L1 integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

What condition can I put on a function f to guarantee its fourier transform is locally L1 integrable? General intuition is also appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is integrable then its Fourier transform $\hat {f}$ is continuous, hence locally integrable. If $f \in L^{2}$ then $\hat {f} \in L^{2}$ so $\hat {f}$ is again locally integrable.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $||\hat{f}||_{\infty} \leq ||f||_1$ if $f \in L^1$

So $\hat{f}$ is integrable on every compact set.

Comment: You need a little bit more than that because what you have does not guarantee integrability.

Comment: @CameronWilliams..O.p asks about local integrability of FT..not integrability on the whole space..isn't this enough?

Comment: Right that's what I meant. It's not enough because there are bounded functions that are not locally integrable.

Comment: @CameronWilliams ...i do not understand..the F.T of an integrable functions is integrable on every ball..since is it has finite L^{\infty} norm..can you give me an example?

Comment: @CameronWilliams $$\int_{B(x,r)}|\hat{f}| \leq ||f||_{\infty}|B(x,r)|$$

Comment: You know what? I was thinking of the Riemann integral, not $L^1$, for some reason. My bad.